# Can we declare the type of parameters when we define curry-style functions?

Tags: sml

If I define a function with tuple-style parameters, I can define the parameter types and the return types:

```
fun hello(name:String, code:int):String = "hello!"
```

But if I use curry-style, I can only do it like this:

```
fun hello name code = "hello!"
```

Is it possible to add parameter types or return types for the later one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is indeed possible:

```
fun hello (name : string) (code : int) : string = "hello!"
```

However, type-annotations are seldom needed or used in Standard ML, so it's most often preferred to omit them.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do this if the function isn't curried is to specify the full function type, a la Haskell,

```
val hello : string * int -> string = 
  fn (name, code) => "hello!"
```

You can do this with recursive functions too

```
val rec hello : string * int -> string = 
  fn (name, code) => hello ("hello!", 5)
```

Uncurried functions are a bit messier, though the type description is still nicer.

```
val hello : name -> int -> string = 
  fn name => fn code => "hello!"
```

Comment: Alternatively, one can denote the type afterwards using `val _ = hello : string * int -> string`