# ML programming language - Curry Function

Tags: sml, ml

I need to find a function with the signature of:

```
'a -> 'b -> ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b
```

So i tried to do it like this:

```
fun f a b g = g(a,b)
```

and got the result:

```
val f = fn : 'a -> 'b -> ('a * 'b -> 'c) -> 'c
```

How can I set this `c` to a `b` as required?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `g(a,b)` does not restrict the resulting type.

The only value of type `'b` that you have access to is the second argument, so you need to return that somewhere, or use it to somehow restrict the result.

A very simple solution is to add a condition,

```
- fun f a b g = if false then b else g(a,b);
val f = fn : 'a -> 'b -> ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b
```

---

Addendum, weeks later, as I suddenly remembered a more elegant solution, without the ugly conditional.
Since `g`'s result should have the same type as its second argument, you can feed it its own result.
This will force `b` and `g(a,b)` to have the same type:

```
- fun f a b g = g(a, g(a,b));
val f = fn : 'a -> 'b -> ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b
```

Comment: The reasoning is correct if all you had in the language were the implicitly typed expressions, and it is an interesting exercise for learning static type inference. However the language does support type annotations, hence in practice you wouldn’t introduce useless runtime code like that.

Comment: @Maëlan Yes, and since this isn't practice but an exercise in understanding type inference, adding explicit type annotations is cheating.

Comment: Ah, that wasn’t written in the question, but now that you say it, maybe it is?

Answer (score 2):

You can write an explicit type annotation, for instance:

```ml
fun f a b (g : _ * 'b -> 'b) = g(a,b)
(* val f = fn : 'a -> 'b -> ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b *)
```

The inferred type `'a -> 'b -> ('a * 'b -> 'c) -> 'c` is strictly more general than the type `'a -> 'b -> ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b` you impose.

On type annotations for functions, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543115/can-we-declare-the-type-of-parameters-when-we-define-curry-style-functions).